# Replace generic character in a Java string

Tags: java, android

I'm wondering about how to replace generic characters in a Java string:

```
String original = "alt width = (SOME NUMBERS)"
```

and I want to make it like

```
String edited = "alt width = 640"
```

I haven't found out anything about on the web.

Comment: The `replace` method...?

Answer (score 2):

To be generic enough to replace any integer number:

```
int number; // this can be any integer
String original = String.format("alt width = %d",number);
```

Or if the numbers are represented as a String e.g "111,121"

```
String numbers;
String original = String.format("alt width = %s",numbers);
```

Comment: or, if the op wanted multiple numbers, you could do `String.format("alt width = %s",numbers);` where `numbers` is String representation of a list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` method should do the trick:

```
String edited = original.replace("(SOME NUMBERS)", "640");
```

EDIT:
Based on the clarification in the comments, you could just remove the last three characters and replace them with what you need:

```
String edited = original.substring(0, original.length() - 3) + "640";
```

Comment: It's not this the point... With "(SOME NUMBERS)", I was intending three numbers which can be any number between 100 and 999.

Comment: @user8628026 definitely not clear from the OP. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer is String.replace option. but you already got that answer.

A more generic option is using regular expressions:

```
String original = "alt width = 123";
int someNumbers = 640;
String edited=original.replaceFirst("[0-9]+",Integer.toString(someNumbers));
System.out.println(edited);
```

This will replace any numbers on the string. So the input string can be different but you'll get the same results:

```
String original = "alt width = 123 cm";
String original = "alt width = 123; alt height = 456";  //only 123 will be replaced 456 will be left as is.
```

You can modify the regex to fit other criteria.